# Coupled vs Decoupled backend-frontend

Tags: rest, design-patterns, architecture

I have an asp.net website project that uses APIs as a back-end, i need to totally decouple my front-end from my back-end apis, so I have created one RESTful service in my back-end project and now i want to consume it in the front-end. I assume i have two solutions:

- Build my model only in the back-end, and add reference to the front-end, to avoid re-writing the same model in the front-end again. (Coupled)
- Build two exact models in both back-end and front-end. (Decoupled)

**Pros:**

Solution 1)

- Avoids re-writing the same model in the front-end again.
- Forces updating front-end model once back-end changes *(otherwise build error)*

Solution 2)

- Helps decoupling my front-end from the back-end.
- Will avoid build errors if back-end model changes. *(Front-end exceptions)*

Please advise which approach is better design, and if you have suggestions please share.

Comment: http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

Comment: @DavidOsborne Good read, but could not find an answer to my bottom-line question (rewrite model? or reference model?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your speed of change for both backend and front-end and how well your tooling supports it, but there is a reason why in most cases people just use two models.

(That reason is that it is very hard to get this right and it reduces your agility enormously.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will not want the same model in the front-end as in the back-end:

1. Decoupling is good.  There's no reason to have your front end coupled in any way to your back end.
2. Your data is naturally structured differently in the front end vs. the back end.
3. You may eventually have multiple front-end apps using the same back end.
4. A particular front-end may consume a different (set of) back ends